# Cannot see databases present on mongodb server desktop, from a remote desktop on same network

Tags: python-3.x, mongodb, pymongo, remote-server

I am running mongodb server on a desktop using mongod --bind_ip_all without any authentication.I want to access a database by two users at same time.
On the same network, I am connecting to that server using pymongo client.
Connection works but when I run client.list_database_names(), it shows ['admin','config','local'] only.

using 'show dbs' on server machine it shows ['admin','config','local','mydatabase']

```
import pymongo

client = pymongo.MongoClient("192.168.43.103",27017)

print(client.list_database_names())
```

Comment: Seems odd. Are you certain it's the same server? Try inserting a few records using both the shell and pymongo and see if they show up in the other.